# How to find the width of a div using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you find the current width of a `<div>` in a cross-browser compatible way *without* using a library like jQuery?

Comment: +1 for the "no jQuery" comment :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding offsetWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth and -Height, respectively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively) (which, indeed, has been asked much later, but still has a **much more elaborate answer**).

Answer (score 540, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth
```

- [element.offsetWidth (MDC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth)

Comment: That, or `cientWidth`, altho I don't know the real difference.

Comment: `offsetWidth` includes border width, `clientWidth` does not.

Comment: When myDiv had no CSS rule but had "width" and "height" defined in the tag, offsetWidth returned the parent width. Not a problem I just added the CSS rule and it worked fine.

Comment: offsetHeight  always zero in IE11

Comment: @nim if your div has `display: none` or is not part of the document, it will always have zero offset height.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively) has a detailed visual explanation of the difference between `offsetWidth` and `clientWidth`.

Answer (score 68):

You can use `clientWidth` or `offsetWidth` [Mozilla developer network reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)

It would be like:

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").clientWidth; // returns number, like 728
```

or with borders width :

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").offsetWidth; // 728 + borders width
```

Answer (score 20):

All Answers are right, but i still want to give some other alternatives that may work.

If you are looking for the assigned width (ignoring padding, margin and so on) you could use.

```
getComputedStyle(element).width; //returns value in px like "727.7px"
```

getComputedStyle allows you to access all styles of that elements. For example: padding, paddingLeft, margin, border-top-left-radius and so on.

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use the getBoundingClientRect function. Please note that getBoundingClientRect will return an empty rect if the element's display is 'none'.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if(elem) {
   var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
   console.log(rect.width);  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also search the DOM using ClassName. For example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")
```

This will return an array.  If there is one particular property you are interested in. For example:

```
var divWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")[0].clientWidth;
```

`divWidth` will now be equal to the the width of the first element in your div array.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't have to use `document.getElementById("mydiv")`  .
You can simply use the id of the div, like:

`var w = mydiv.clientWidth;`
or
`var w = mydiv.offsetWidth;`
etc.

Answer (score 0):

call below method on div or body tag onclick="show(event);"
function show(event) {

```
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;

        var ele = document.getElementById("tt");
        var width = ele.offsetWidth;
        var height = ele.offsetHeight;
        var half=(width/2);
       if(x>half)
        {
          //  alert('right click');
            gallery.next();
        }
        else
       {
           //   alert('left click');
            gallery.prev();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of getting computed style is waiting till page is rendered. It can be done in the following manner. Pay attention to timeout on getting `auto` values.

```
function getStyleInfo() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('__root__'));
        if (style.height == 'auto') {
            getStyleInfo();
        }
        // IF we got here we can do actual business logic staff
        console.log(style.height, style.width);
    }, 100);
};

window.onload=function() { getStyleInfo(); };
```

If you use just

```
window.onload=function() {
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('__root__'));
}
```

you can get `auto` values for width and height because browsers does not render till full load is performed.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all...