# Div width Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the entire width of a div including margins without using JQuery?

```
 div.outerWidth
```

doesn't seem to work and `clientWidth` excludes margins.

Comment: jQuery has a lot of built in syntax-sugar that deals with the differences between web browsers, especially in the way that each browser handles its box-model. However, some more searching around here might have revealed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div

Comment: offsetWidth does not include margins

Comment: It's important to remember that jQuery is built on top of JavaScript. That is to say, anything jQuery can do, JavaScript can do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, there is no single property value to get this.

Basically you need to get the margin width (left and right) and add them to your existing dimensions. Additionally, unless you are using box-sizing (By default you are **not**) you will need to add padding left and right as well.

You can use getComputedStyle to get the actual values you require. For example:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
```

Edit:
I forgot border :P.... left and right border width as well...

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below code, there is being alert total width of div 220 including margin.

```
<style>
    #myDiv{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        margin:10px;
    }
</style>
<div id='myDiv'>
</div>
<script>
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
    var leftMargin = parseInt(style.marginLeft.match(/\d+/));
    var rightMargin = parseInt(style.marginRight.match(/\d+/));
    alert(div.clientWidth + leftMargin + rightMargin);
</script>
```