# Repeatedly reduce the width of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the width of a specific `<div>` to get smaller by 50px every time a JavaScript function is called.

I tried

```
document.getElementById("Zivot").style.width = "100px";
```

But that just sets the width, and doesn't add or subtract it.

Comment: I would recommend determining the width, then subtracting 50

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code. Get the width using offsetWidth and reduce it by 50px every time.

```
var element = document.getElementById('Zivot'); 
element.style.width = (element.offsetWidth - 50) + 'px';
```

Comment: Might want to change the id.

Comment: Did it just performed on this site :P

Answer (score 2):

A pure Javascript way of getting this working-

```
var zivotID = document.getElementById("Zivot");
zivotID.style.width = zivotID.offsetWidth - 50;
```

**document.getElementById("Zivot").style.width** or **myID.style.width** - Here you actually set the value of width. I mean, you wait for a value to be given so that you can set.

**document.getElementById("Zivot").offsetWidth** or **myID.offsetWidth** - This gets the width of the div/element.

Some reference links-

[How to find the width of a div using raw Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-raw-javascript)

[HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)

[How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentWidth = $('#Zivot').width();
$('#Zivot').css('width', currentWidth - 50 + 'px');
```

Comment: One of his tags is jQuery.