# Javascript returns no width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know it will be totally embarassing, but I'm a blockhead today!

Why doesn't Javascript return the width here?

The output of the below code is:

**JQUERY** says: 500;

**JAVASCRIPT** says: (that's the problem. Javascript returns just NOTHING)

Here' the **fiddle-link:** https://jsfiddle.net/w62zg76f/1/

**UPDATE:** Thank you guys! **Solution is .offsetWidth of course**

(I knew it would be embarassing :-)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#result").html(
  "<br />JQUERY says: " + $("#divA").width() + 
  "<br />JAVASCRIPT says: " + document.getElementById("divA").style.width
  );

});
```

```css
#divA{
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divA">I'm a div. Get my width!</div>

<!-- Just for output -->
<p id=result></p>
```

Comment: As there is no inline styles `width` applied to element, `.style.width` will be undefined. [How to find the width of a div using raw Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-raw-javascript) and [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](//stackoverflow.com/q/294250)

Comment: Probably a good time to mention that if you separated out your lines of code, built your HTML, and then tried to apply it, you'd probably be able to see the actual error.

Comment: oh gosh. Yes! And how to get the width WITHOUT inline styles applied. I already tried without .style

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively

Comment: if you actually googled it (like most of us who gave answers probably did) you'd have found the SO answer for this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

document.getElementById("divA").style.width return you undefined, you have to use the offsetWidth

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#result").html(
  "<br />JQUERY says: " + $("#divA").width() + 
  "<br />JAVASCRIPT says: " + document.getElementById("divA").offsetWidth
  );

});
```

```css
#divA{
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA">I'm a div. Get my width!</div>




<!-- Just for output -->
<p id=result></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `offsetWidth`

```
$("#result").html(
"<br />JQUERY says: " + $("#divA").width() + 
"<br />JAVASCRIPT says: " + document.getElementById("divA").offsetWidth;
);
```

[HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight` properties. Note they belong to the element, not `.style`.

```
"<br />JAVASCRIPT says: " + document.getElementById("divA").offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

use document.getElementById("divA").offsetWidth instead.