# How to get the CSS width/height of a container element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If the size of an element, say for this case - a body element, is not known or it can be mentioned in any of the mentioned formats mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width, is it possible to get the size of the containing element for that element?

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <p id="test">This is a paragraph!</p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here say size of body is set to 50% or 300px, how can I get the size of the whole document? Apologize if this is stupid, new to this side of things. This is not a duplicate of [How to find the width of a div using vanilla JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-vanilla-javascript), because I am asking for the width of a container element and not the element itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the width of a div using vanilla JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: You could try to traverse up one parent node with [Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) in your JS

Comment: @MyLibary Really isn't a duplicate even if it's similar.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe this is a duplicate, since the question is about the container element and not the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parentNode property to find the parent of an element.  You can then use the offsetWidth and offsetHeight properties to find the width/height of the element.

```
var parentElem = document.getElementById('test').parentNode;
var parentWidth = parentElem.offsetWidth;
var parentHeight = parentElem.offsetHeight;
```