# Get width of div with javascript

Tags: javascript

Why `document.getElementById("mydiv").style.width` doesn't return the width of mydiv ? It returns an empty string. Some people suggested using offsetWidth, but it doesn't make sense to me why you can't get it from style.width.

Comment: Please share a small demo of this where we can see the issue in action.

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-vanilla-javascript

Comment: It would only return width value if set by a style via css, otherwise you would need use javascript width. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26718430/10634638

Comment: .style.width if there a inline style on the container.
you may check .offsetWidth for the container

Answer (score 5):

The topic of DOM element dimensions is complicated.

You probably want one of :

**[`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)**

> The `HTMLElement.offsetWidth` read-only property returns the layout
>   width of an element as an integer.
>
> Typically, `offsetWidth` is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS
>   width, including any borders, padding, and vertical scrollbars (if
>   rendered). It does not include the width of pseudo-elements such as
>   `::before` or `::after`.
>
> If the element is hidden (for example, by setting `style.display` on the
>   element or one of its ancestors to "none"), then `0` is returned.

**[`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)**

> The `Element.clientWidth` property is zero for inline elements and
>   elements with no CSS; otherwise, it's the inner width of an element in
>   pixels. It includes padding but excludes borders, margins, and
>   vertical scrollbars (if present).
>
> When `clientWidth` is used on the root element (the `<html>` element), (or
>   on `<body>` if the document is in quirks mode), the viewport's width
>   (excluding any scrollbar) is returned. This is a special case of
>   clientWidth.

**[`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)**

> The `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` method returns the size of an
>   element and its position relative to the viewport.
>
> The element's size is equal to its width/height + padding in the case
>   that the standard box model is being used, or width/height only if
>   `box-sizing: border-box` has been set on it.

jQuery hides some of this complexity behind a [`.width`](https://api.jquery.com/width/) method.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)
const d1 = $('#unstyled')
const d2 = $('#stylesheet')
const d3 = $('#inline')
const details = $('#details')

details.innerHTML = (`
<table>
  <tr>
<td><h2>A</h2> offsetWidth: '${d1.offsetWidth}', clientWidth: '${d1.clientWidth}', getBoundingClientRect().width: '${d1.getBoundingClientRect().width}', style.width: '${d1.style.width}'
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><h2>B</h2> offsetWidth: '${d2.offsetWidth}', clientWidth: '${d2.clientWidth}', getBoundingClientRect().width: '${d2.getBoundingClientRect().width}', style.width: '${d2.style.width}'
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><h2>C</h2> offsetWidth: '${d3.offsetWidth}', clientWidth: '${d3.clientWidth}', getBoundingClientRect().width: '${d3.getBoundingClientRect().width}', style.width: '${d3.style.width}'
</td>
  </tr>
</table>`)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
}
#stylesheet {
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px; 
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
div {       
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1px silver inset;
}
table {
  border: 0px;
}
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="unstyled">A</div>
<div id="stylesheet">B</div>
<div id="inline" style="width:100px;height:50px;text-align: center;line-height: 50px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; border: 5px solid red;">C</div>
<section id="details"></section>
```