# Appending an Element on Mousedown Into Specific Div Element Only

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mousedown, onmousedown

I am trying to add circles when the event `mousedown` is generated into the square-one (grey square) only. If the mouse hovers outside of the square-one, it should not insert any circles anywhere else such as square-two(green square).

Question: How can I set the limits for the circles such that they are only inserted within the square-one boundaries? Thank you for your help.

```
***********
JavaScript
***********

let count = 1
let greySquare = document.getElementById("square-one")
let mousePosition;
let circlesArray = []

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=>{

  let circle = document.createElement('div')
  let circleHeight = 40
  let circleWidth = 40

  mousePosition = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }


  circle.style.height = `${circleHeight}px`
  circle.style.width = `${circleWidth}px`;
  circle.style.borderRadius = "50%"

  circle.style.backgroundColor = `#F0B27A`
  circle.style.position = "absolute"
  circle.style.left = (mousePosition.x - (circleWidth/2)) + "px"
  circle.style.top = (mousePosition.y - (circleHeight/2)) + "px"
  circle.style.lineHeight = `${circleHeight}px`
  circle.style.display = 'flex';
  circle.style.cursor = 'pointer'
  circle.style.justifyContent = 'center';
  circle.style.border = 'none'

  circle.textContent = count++
  greySquare.appendChild(circle)
  circlesArray.push(circle)

})
```

```
********
  HTML
********

  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="square-one"></div>
        <div id="square-two"></div>
      </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```
******
CSS
******
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  position: relative;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#square-one{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
#square-two{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use your code, the circles aren't being put where I actually click.

That is because you're using the mouse's position (which is relative to the page) to *detect* where you will put the circles, but then you append them to the

`graySquare`, which doesn't start at (0,0). If you append them to the `.contaner` instead, you'll be ok.

```js
document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(circle)
```

Then regarding the *set the limits for the circles such that they are only inserted within the square-one boundaries*, you need to get the position (x and y), width and height of the `squareOne` and only proceed if the click occurs within those.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=>{

  mousePosition = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }

  let greySquarePosition = greySquare.getBoundingClientRect();

  if(!(mousePosition.x>=greySquarePosition.left + window.scrollX&&
    mousePosition.x<=greySquarePosition.left + window.scrollX + greySquarePosition.width&&
    mousePosition.y>=greySquarePosition.top + window.scrollY&&
    mousePosition.y<=greySquarePosition.top + window.scrollY + greySquarePosition.height)) 
    return;
    // ...
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222246/3386085) to get the position of the div, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55895345/3386085) to get its width and height (although they ended up being the same *solution*).

**EDIT!**

I kept thinking about this and there's a more obvious, more elegant solution (to me at least). You add the event listener to the `graySquare` and not the whole `document`.

```
greySquare.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=> ...
```

Then you don't need the ugly part where you check if the mouse is within the limits.

You can even bind the same function to different squares. Check the updated snippet.

```js
let count = 1
let greySquare = document.getElementById("square-one")
let greenSquare = document.getElementById("square-two")
let mousePosition;
let circlesArray = []

greySquare.addEventListener('mousedown', paintCircles.bind(null, '#F0B27A'), false);
greenSquare.addEventListener('mousedown', paintCircles.bind(null, '#fa0123'), false);

function paintCircles(color, event){

    mousePosition = {
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    }

    let circle = document.createElement('div')
    let circleHeight = 40
    let circleWidth = 40

    circle.style.height = `${circleHeight}px`
    circle.style.width = `${circleWidth}px`;
    circle.style.borderRadius = "50%"

    circle.style.backgroundColor = `${color}`
    circle.style.position = "absolute"
    circle.style.left = (mousePosition.x - (circleWidth/2)) + "px"
    circle.style.top = (mousePosition.y - (circleHeight/2)) + "px"
    circle.style.lineHeight = `${circleHeight}px`
    circle.style.display = 'flex';
    circle.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    circle.style.justifyContent = 'center';
    circle.style.border = 'none'

    circle.textContent = count++;
    document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(circle)
    circlesArray.push(circle)

}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body{
    position: relative;
  }

  .container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #square-one{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-right: 100px;
  }
  #square-two{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="square-one"></div>
    <div id="square-two"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Also I noticed that you have a getTop function but its not used anywhere in the code. Did you mean to do something with it?

Comment: @night_programmer ah no just forgot to remove it

Comment: Thanks for the edited code. That makes it so much easier. Cant believe that did not cross my mind. Thanks!