# Getting width of div class row

Tags: html, jquery

I need to get the width of this div

```
<div class='row WidthAdjust'></div>
```

But it is proving way more difficult than I anticipated, below is some of the things I have already tried

```
  // var row = document.getElementsByClassName("WidthAdjust").width()
      var row = document.getElementsByClassName("WidthAdjust")
      var rowWidth = parseFloat($(row).width())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-vanilla-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the width of a div using vanilla JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div-using-vanilla-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var data = row.getBoundingClientRect()` to get `DOMRect` object. This object will have the size of the element and its position relative to view port.

Use `data.width` to get the width specifically.